# Segmentation Fault in LinkedList

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am getting a SIGSEGV in the following code, I am not sure why? Everything seems fine.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
    explicit Node(int data): data(data), next(nullptr){}
};


class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node *head, *tail;
public:
    LinkedList(): head(nullptr), tail(nullptr){}
    void pushBack(int data);
    void print();
};

void LinkedList::pushBack(int data)
{
    Node* temp = new Node(data);
    if(head == nullptr && tail == nullptr)
    {
        head = tail = temp;
        tail = tail->next;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = tail->next;
    }
}

void LinkedList::print()
{
    Node* temp = head;
    while(temp != nullptr)
    {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main()
{
    LinkedList lst;
    lst.pushBack(34);
    lst.pushBack(35);
    lst.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `tail` pointer? What use is that?

Comment: Hint: What if `head` is fine, but `tail` is `nullptr`? You set yourself up here for failure.

Comment: If you have a `head` and `tail` and one `Node`, `head` and `tail` should point to the same `Node`, right?

Answer (score 2):

Your `pushBack()` function sabotages itself:

1. Before the first call `head` and `tail` are both `nullptr`.
2. After the first call `head` is set, `tail` is still `nullptr`
3. During the second call you access `tail->next` but `tail` is still `nullptr`, so it crashes.

It could be as simple to fix as this:

```cpp
void LinkedList::pushBack(int data)
{
    Node* temp = new Node(data);

    // Testing tail here doesn't matter, just test head
    if (head == nullptr)
    {
        // Set head and tail to be the same thing, length == 1
        head = tail = temp;
        // Ensure that tail is not set to tail->next which would be
        // nullptr again, leading to further sabotage.
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Careful with that assumption. You also have `tail = tail->next;`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is at the `if` block in the `pushBack(int data)` member function. When it's called for the first time then head and tail are set to a new address but `tail = tail->next` sets the tail pointer to `nullptr`. So, when the `pushBack()` is called the next time then we are trying to dereference a nullptr and trying to assign an address into it. Removing `tail = tail->next` from the if block will fix the code. So, the final `pushBack()` will look like:

```
void LinkedList::pushBack(int data)
{
    Node* temp = new Node(data);
    if(head == nullptr && tail == nullptr)
    {
        head = tail = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = tail->next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use `gdb` to find the source of the segfault.

Assume the above code is saved to a file called `linked_list.cpp`.

```
$ g++ -g linked_list.cpp -o linked_list
$ gdb linked_list
GNU gdb (GDB) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
...
Reading symbols from linked_list...
(gdb) run

Starting program: linked_list 

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000055555555520e in LinkedList::pushBack (this=0x7fffffffe940, data=35) at linked_list.cpp:32
32          tail->next = temp;
(gdb) print tail
$1 = (Node *) 0x0
```

From this we see that `tail` is `nullptr` on line 32. Dereferencing a `nullptr` will cause a segfault.